# Spring Boot 3.2: Behavior change of WebMVC databinding for query parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

When attempting to upgrade our Spring Boot + Spring Web based REST API from Spring Boot 3.1.6 to 3.2.0, we encountered an unexpected change of behavior in databinding of query parameters. In some cases it leads to errors, in others it might cause tricky bugs.

The following example shows our situation: a REST controller with a simple GET endpoint that retrieves its parameters as an object that contains a nested object:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/builder")
public class DemoLombokDataBuilder {

   @Data
   @Builder
   static class Dto {
      String field;
      Nested nested;
   }

   @Data
   static class Nested {
      String nestedField;
   }

   @GetMapping
   public String demo(Dto dto) {
      String result = dto.getField();

      if (dto.getNested() != null)
         result += dto.getNested().getNestedField();
      else
         result += ", nested is empty";

      return result;
   }
```

With Spring Boot 3.1.6, the result of calling the endpoint with or without the nested field are:

| URL | Result |
| --- | --- |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo | foo, nested is empty |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo&nested.nestedField=bar | foobar |

With Spring Boot 3.2.0 however, the results are:

| URL | Result |
| --- | --- |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo | **foonull** |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo&nested.nestedField=bar | foobar |

So instead of not instantiating the nested object at all when its field is not provided, Spring 3.2 instantiates the nested object with empty values. This can lead to bugs - and it's even worse when validation is used and the nested object has mandatory fields annotated with `@NotNull`. In that case Spring Boot 3.2 throws HTTP 400, while the requests worked fine in 3.1.

**Has anyone else encountered similar problems, or did we miss something from the docs or upgrade guides?**
Right now, this seems like a bug to us because it can lead to tricky bugs due to changed runtime behavior.

*Additional Details*

In my further tests, the issue only occurs when the DTO class can only be constructed via an all-args-constructor.
With this DTO:

```java
   @Data
   static class Dto {

      String field;
      Nested nested;
   }
```

both 3.1 and 3.2 have the same results:

| URL | Result |
| --- | --- |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo | foo, nested is empty |
| http://localhost:8080/builder?field=foo&nested.nestedField=bar | foobar |

I pushed the full examples to this Github repo: https://github.com/flpa/springboot-databinder-change-tests

*Edit: I also created an issue on Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31821*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Spring Framework, it has been fixed and marked for release in Spring Framework version 6.1.2.

For more information, see Github issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31821

Answer (score 0):

I started facing the same issue while performing an upgrade from Spring Boot 2 to 3.

I just downgrade the POM spring boot version from `3.2.2` to `3.1.6` and it works.

I migrate from 2.7.x to 3.2.2 and the data binders started failing for no reason... After a looooong research, the downgrade was the uniquely solution.

[image: Git diff]